# Seriously struggling with Ito's lemma, and understanding what this paper does!!!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-pde

So, this is a theorem that I need to apply on a simpler system, and understanding it thus far has been the bane of my existence. I was wondering how exactly both Ito's formula and the Burkholder-Davies-Gundy Theorem are applied in each case. I think that so far I have not been able to mentally conquer Ito's Theorem. It makes sense to me where the later terms come from in the proof, but not the first ones. Also, I am struggling to see how the theorem is applied.

An important definition in this proof is the following,

\begin{equation}
 \mathcal{Z}_{k_1} = \alpha_k \epsilon^{-1} \int^T_0 e^{-\epsilon^{-2}\lambda_k(T-\tau) }d\tilde{\beta}_\tau,\end{equation} where $\alpha_k$ is a coefficient related to damping, $\lambda_k$ is a complex eigenvalue of the main SPDE that this paper is looking at, and $\epsilon$ is a small parameter. $\tilde{\beta}_\tau$ is a rescaled Brownian motion.

The theorem is as follows! Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It seems like you are trying to understand research material without having first mastered the background stochastic calculus. I think you should take a few months to go back and read all this material from a good book like Karatzas or Revuz, and do some exercises, then this stuff will become much clearer and more natural.

Comment: Also, it will help others to understand your question better if you post the link to the complete paper in your question.